# Change Stackapplet tray icon to be more unity-like

Tags: icons, stackapplet

With the current version of Stackapplet from the Software Center (thank you to this app's developers, real basic, real useful app) both the "Light" and "Dark" themes look out of place in comparison to the rest of the icons in the tray. Dark blends in too much and light is the  right color but is too large in comparison to the other icons. Can I change the icon, or,  better yet, can the default icon be changed to look better with unity? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you can you can fix this by opening StackApplet's icon in the `/usr/share/pixmaps` folder with administrative privileges. Shrink the size of the image, then save. Restart StackApplet, and the icon in the notification area will be smaller.